# parsing string for a float

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

I am reading in an XML file and reading a specific value of 10534360.9

When I parse the string for a decimal ( `decimal.Parse(afNodes2[0][column1].InnerText)` ) I get `10534360.9`, but when I parse it for a float ( `float.Parse(afNodes2[0][column1].InnerText)` ) I get `1.053436E+07`.

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the value represented in "E" or "exponential" notation.

`1.053436E+07` is equivalent to `1.053436 x 10^7`, or `10,534,360`, which is the most precise way .NET can store `10,534,360.9` in the [`System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) (`float`) data type (32 bits, 7 digits of precision).

You're seeing it represented that way because it is the default format produced by the `Single.ToString()` method, which the debugger uses to display values on the watch screens, console, etc.

**EDIT**

It probably goes without saying, but if you want to retain the precision of the original value in the XML, you could choose a data type that can retain more information about your numbers:

- [`System.Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) (64 bits, 15-16 digits)
- [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) (128 bits, 28-29 significant digits)

Answer (score 1):

1.053436E+07 == 10534360.9

Those numbers are the same, just displayed differently.

Answer (score 1):

Because float has a precision of 7 digits.
Decimal has a precision of 28 digits.

Answer (score 0):

When viewing the data in a debugger, or displaying it via `.ToString`, by default it might be [formatted using scientific notation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5dbkt9x(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Some examples of the return value are "100", "-123,456,789", "123.45e+6", "500", "3.1416", "600", "-0.123", and "-Infinity".

To format it as exact output, use the `R` (round trip) format string:

```
myFloat.ToString("R");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx